# How to setup route to browse internal website through openvpn?

Tags: routing, openvpn

I'm totally newbie in network, and I encountered a problem that I have no clue how to solve.

We have an internal appliance plugged in the internal network, and there's a cloud instance that uses OpenVPN to communicate with this appliance. Right now I need to use this cloud instance to browse an internal website, but I don't know how to configure to make the browser request go through the tun0 interface. Can anybody help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a route to the resources on the other side of the tunnel using the `route` command and bind it to the tunnel interface. Usually you'll set the gateway for this route to be someone on the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I bind it to the tunnel interface, how's that going to affect my browsing to other websites? Sorry but I don't have much knowledge about it.

Comment: If it's not your default route, then you'll have a split tunnel situation. If you set your default route to the other side of the tunnel instead of a new static route, then all traffic will traverse the tunnel.